# React render function not returning the simple HTML codes from it's components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am creating a project using MERN stack.In my App.js I imported some react component but while I run it shows a blank White screen.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar"
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
      <Route path="/" component={Navbar} />
      <br/>
      <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <h1>Pantha</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: So where is react-bootstrap? You use plain bootstrap, please remove the tag.

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the console?

Comment: no error message@IgorGonak

Comment: I see you are using react-router wrong. Please read https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Comment: Depends what version they're using @IgorGonak

Comment: what do you mean with "they"? You didn't wrote what version YOU are using. So I assumed you are using the latest one.

Comment: @IgorGonak I am not the OP.

Comment: haha, oh I see...

Comment: Please mark as solved and post your solution please :)